# How to define Angular nested routes for independent pages navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic-Angular web application on which I am trying to create a website-like routing scheme, with nested routes of otherwise independent pages.

So far I had the routes defined like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "monitor", loadChildren: () => import('./pages/storyline/story-list/story-list.module').then(m => m.StoryListPageModule) },
  { path: "monitor/story", pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/storyline/story-home/story-home.module').then(m => m.StoryHomePageModule) }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is how I go from the parent page (from `StoryListPage` on route `monitor`) to the child page (`StoryHomePage` on route `monitor/story`)

```
this.router.navigate(["story"], { replaceUrl: true, relativeTo: this.route });
```

This works fine, but when I refresh the page on `monitor/story` route, it doesn't load the page and returns the following error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/monitor/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/monitor/styles.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
story:34          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
story:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/monitor/scripts.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
favicon.png:1          GET http://localhost:8100/monitor/assets/icon/favicon.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Everything I've found so far was about nested routes, having `router-outlet` in each parent page, and defining child routes, which is probably not what I need for this. I'm just looking for basic page navigation between routes that have the nested-style format like a website, but not actually nesting pages within one another.

It seems the solution described in the question is pretty close to what I need, if I could solve that error.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
ionic generate page your-page-name
```

inside the page folder directory in which you want to create nested routes.